# Custom (multiple words) title for Sphinx Admonition

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I would like to create a custom admonition with a title made of several words (e.g. "Historical Notes"). I came up with a dirty trick using `.admonition-title:after` in my `custom.css` file:

```css
.admonition-historical {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: rgb(153,102,153);
}

.rst-content .admonition-historical .admonition-title {
    background: #AD85AD;
}

.rst-content .admonition-historical {
   background: #EDE5ED
}

.rst-content .admonition-historical .admonition-title:before {
    content: "  ";
}

.rst-content .admonition-historical .admonition-title:after {
    content: " notes";
}
```

That works fines in the HTML document, but not in the LaTeX build, where it appears as "Historical" only.

What would be the proper way to define an admonition with a complex multi-word title, that renders well in both HTML and LaTeX?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure whether I understand your question properly. However, there is `admonition` directive that allows setting a title in its argument:

```
.. admonition:: This is generic admonition title

   Generic admonition are rarely used but has one important benefit over
   specific ones: author may define admonition title in directive argument.
   Specific admonitions gets its type as title (danger has danger as title
   etc.).
```

Comment: But then can I set the colors as well?

Comment: Colors and appereance in general depends on CSS styles applied to output HTML generated by Sphinx. Add `:class:` option to admonition:: directive to apply CSS class. For example  `:class: admonition-historical` and HTML <div> will have "class=adminition-historical".